# How To Remove Single Blank Line Only - Keep Multiple Blank Lines

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I have some data where I want to keep the multiple blank lines and remove the single blank lines only. My data look like this:

```
1

2

3

4


5


6

7

8



9

10
```

I would like the output to be:

```
1
2
3  
4


5


6
7
8



9
10
```

I have tried working with the following commands, but I can't seem to get it to work:

```
awk ' /^$/ { print; } /./ { printf("%s ", $0); }'
```

And

```
sed 'N;/^\n$/d;P;D'
```

Also, I tried using `cat -s` but that doesn't necessarily take out the blank lines. Furthermore, I have played around with `sed '/^$/'` but cant specify single lines only. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using gnu-awk it is pretty simple:

```
awk -v RS='\n+' '{printf "%s", $0 (length(RT) != 2 ? RT : "\n")}' file

1
2
3
4


5


6
7
8



9
10
```

- Using `-v RS='\n+'` we constitute 1 or more line breaks as record separator
- Using `length(RT)` we check how many line breaks are after each record
- we print `RT` (original captured value) if `length != 2`

**Alternative `awk` command**:

```
awk -v RS='\n{3,}' '{gsub(/\n{2}/, "\n", $0); printf "%s", $0 RT}' file
```

Comment: Very nice use of `RT`!

Comment: Indeed, very well done! Note you can move `$0` to the common part, since it happens all the times, as well as use ORS since it defaults to `\n` anyway: `awk -v RS='\\n+' '{printf "%s%s", $0, (length(RT) != 2 ? RT : ORS)}' file`.

Comment: Hey @anubhava, thanks for the great solution. I didn't know about RT. The first one works perfectly.

Comment: Hi @anubhava, this works great in the shell. But, cron doesn't like it. I any idea what I'm not escaping?

Comment: Sorry don't know much about that without details. I suggest you create a new question for cron problem and you will get instant help.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU sed (minor modifications needed for BSD/OSX):

```
$ sed -E ':a; N; $!ba; :b; s/([^\n])\n\n([^\n])/\1\n\2/g; tb' input
1
2
3
4


5


6
7
8



9
10
```

#### How it works

- `:a; N; $!ba`

  Read the whole file in at once.

  Here, `a` is a label.  `N` reads in the next line.  `$!ba` branches back to label unless we are on the last line.
- `:b; s/([^\n])\n\n([^\n])/\1\n\2/g; tb`

  Replace double-newlines with single newlines.  Repeat as often as necessary.

  Here `b` is a label.  The `s` command removes the double newlines.  If any double-newlines were removed, then `tb` branches back to label `b`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\S/!b;n;N;/^\s*\n\s*\S/D' file
```

If a line is empty print it. Otherwise, print the line and fetch the next two lines and if the first of these is empty but the second is not, delete the first and repeat.